# Cannot add attribute node to an element node that already has non attribute or namespace children

Tags: xml

getting error when trying to transform XSL  file:

Cannot add attribute 'encid'='' to element 'td'

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode - Please don't post your code or parts of it as image. For closer information as to why and what you can do take a look at the link above.

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? It is telling you what the problem is. Order matters in XML, and you're adding nodes out of the required order. Attributes come first after the opening element, you can't add them after other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Before your `xsl:attribute`(and the `xsl:if`) you have an

```
<xsl:value select="name" />&#160;
```

That conflicts with the attribute, because `xsl:attribute` elements have to be *before* any value nodes. So put the attributes before any value nodes and your problem will vanish.